# Can't get Set of selected items filled from Adapter in Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, set, adapter

I have a custom CursorAdapter that retreiving data from my database and set it into listiew. Listview has 4 columns and checkbox. I click on checkbox to select the id of item in the listview (use setOnCheckedChangeListener in my adapter). And store the selected id in Set, that was created by Activity. 
I need to use these saved ids in the button that belongs to Activity (in onClick method) to send sms, email and make a call.
The problem is that I can't retrieve the data from Set. Where is my mistake?

My custom CursorAdapter:

```
public class NotifyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public static final String TAG = NotifyAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
NotifyActivity notifyActivity=new NotifyActivity();
ListView listView;
Cursor c;

public NotifyAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, ListView listView, int flags) {
    super(context, c, 0);
    this.listView = listView;
    this.c = c;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_5col_notifications_send, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


    TextView tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_notifications_full_name);
    ImageView iv_sms_notify = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_sms_notify);
    ImageView iv_email_notify = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_email_notify);
    ImageView iv_call_notify = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_call_notify);
    final CheckBox cb_notify = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chb_person_notify);


    final int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.ID_COLUMN));
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NAME_COLUMN));
    int sms_notify_checked = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.SMS_NOTIFICATION_COLUMN));
    int email_notify_checked = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_COLUMN));
    int call_notify_checked = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CALL_NOTIFICATION_COLUMN));

    tv_name.setText(name);
    if (sms_notify_checked == 1) {
        iv_sms_notify.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_18dp);
    } else iv_sms_notify.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_18dp);

    if (email_notify_checked == 1) {
        iv_email_notify.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_18dp);
    } else iv_email_notify.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_18dp);

    if (call_notify_checked == 1) {
        iv_call_notify.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_black_18dp);
    } else iv_call_notify.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_18dp);


    cb_notify.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                             @Override
                                             public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                                 if (cb_notify.isChecked()) {

                                                     notifyActivity.addToCheckedItemSet(id);
                                                     Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + id);
                                                     notifyActivity.readSet();

                                                 }


                                                 if (!cb_notify.isChecked())

                                                 {
                                                     notifyActivity.readSet();
                                                     if (notifyActivity.isCheckSetContainsId(id)) {
                                                         notifyActivity.deleteFromCheckedItemSet(id);
                                                         Log.d(TAG, "deleted: " + id);
                                                         notifyActivity.readSet();

                                                     }
```

My Activity with listview filled by adapter:

```
public class NotifyActivity extends MenuActivity implements View.OnClickListener/*,
    android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>*/ {

public static final String TAG = NotifyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
ListView listView;
Button btn_send_message;
Button btn_cancel_send_message;
CheckBox cb_notify;
Intent intent;
DBHelper dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase database;
NotifyAdapter notifyAdapter;
Set<Integer> checkedItemsIdSet = new HashSet<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notify);


    setToolbar();

    cb_notify = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chb_person_notify);
    btn_send_message = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_message);
    btn_cancel_send_message = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_send_message);
    btn_send_message.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_cancel_send_message.setOnClickListener(this);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_notifications_send);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            DBHelper.RELATIONSHIP_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{getRelationshipValue()},
            null, null, null, null);
    notifyAdapter = new NotifyAdapter(this, cursor, listView, 0);

    listView.setAdapter(notifyAdapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);



  /*
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();*/

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            DBHelper.RELATIONSHIP_COLUMN + " = ?", new String[]{getRelationshipValue()},
            null, null, null, null);
    notifyAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);


}

private void setToolbar() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_toolbar);
    TextView toolbarTitle_small = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_small_title_toolbar);
    toolbarTitle.setText(getRelationshipValue());
    toolbarTitle_small.setText("NOTIFY");
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
    }
}

public Set<Integer> getCheckedItemsIdSet() {
    return checkedItemsIdSet;
}

public void addToCheckedItemSet(int id) {
    checkedItemsIdSet.add(id);
}

public boolean isCheckSetContainsId(int id) {
    if (checkedItemsIdSet.contains(id))
        return true;
    else return false;
}

public void deleteFromCheckedItemSet(int id) {
    checkedItemsIdSet.remove(id);
}

public void readSet() {
    for (int s : checkedItemsIdSet) {
        Log.d("My set list content: ", String.valueOf(s));
    }
}

private String getRelationshipValue() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String relationship_value = intent.getStringExtra("Relationship");
    return relationship_value;
}

private String message() {
    String message = "test";
    return message;
}

private void sendSMS(int id) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String smsNotificationEnable = "1";
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{DBHelper.PHONE_COLUMN},
            DBHelper.RELATIONSHIP_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.ID_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.SMS_NOTIFICATION_COLUMN + " = ?",
            new String[]{getRelationshipValue(), String.valueOf(id), smsNotificationEnable},
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String destinationAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.PHONE_COLUMN));
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, message(), null, null);
    } else Log.d(TAG, "No sms cursor");
}

private void sendEmail(int id) {
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String emailNotificationEnable = "1";
    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{DBHelper.EMAIL_COLUMN},
            DBHelper.RELATIONSHIP_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.ID_COLUMN + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_COLUMN + " = ?",
            new String[]{getRelationshipValue(), String.valueOf(id), emailNotificationEnable},
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String to = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.EMAIL_COLUMN));
        String subject = "KTK information";
        String message = message();
        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{to});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client"));
    } else Log.d(TAG, "No email cursor");


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_send_message: {
            Log.d(TAG,"on click started");
            readSet();

            for (int checkedId : checkedItemsIdSet) {
                Log.d(TAG,"on click"+checkedId);
                sendSMS(checkedId);
                sendEmail(checkedId);
            }

        }


        case R.id.btn_cancel_send_message:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RespondMapActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: check whether cursor is null or not

Comment: I think the problem is not in a cursor, because the Set is filled by adapter (use Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + id); and  notifyActivity.readSet(); from adapter after selecting the checkbox).

Comment: @PreethiRao I can't read my Set from onClick() in Activity..

Answer (score 0):

Answer - make all methods and variables related to set static.